# MySQL query - how to get a count of number of related tags

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling figuring out a good way to query my required data.  I am using mySQL and php.  Currently, I am making multiple queries and using a bunch of for each loops, however, I still can't get my necessary output.

This might be tough question, so I appreciate anyone who puts in some effort to figure it out!

---

My current tables are as follows:

```
topics_keywords (t_k_id, topic_id, keyword_id)
keywords (keyword_id, keyword)
topics (topic_id, subject, etc)
```

table `topics_keyword` is going to have multiple keywords associated with the same topic_id.

table `keywords` will only have define a single keyword for each keyword_id.

If someone queries for a specific keyword(i.e. sports), I would like to return a list of all associated keywords that relate to the topic_id.

In the below SQL, you'll see that topic 3 is associated with keyword_id's 3(sports) and 4(baseball).  However, note that it is also associated with keyword_id 2(hello).

I simply need a count of how many times 'sports' is associated with baseball. I say simply, but i can't figure out an easy way to do it.

The final output, based on the data below, would need to look something like this:

search term: 'baseball'
final output:

```
count  | keyword
----------------
sports | 2
hello  | 1
```

Heres some mySQL to help go through the data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords` (
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyword_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `keywords`
--

INSERT INTO `keywords` (`keyword_id`, `keyword`) VALUES
(1, 'thebump'),
(2, 'hello'),
(3, 'baseball'),
(4, 'sports'),
(5, 'manga'),
(6, 'naruto'),
(7, 'one piece');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `topics_keywords`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topics_keywords` (
  `t_k_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topics_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t_k_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `topics_keywords`
--

INSERT INTO `topics_keywords` (`t_k_id`, `topics_id`, `keyword_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 2),
(3, 3, 3),
(4, 3, 4),
(5, 4, 3),
(6, 5, 3),
(7, 5, 4),
(8, 6, 3),
(9, 6, 4),
(10, 3, 2);
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: First of all, this is a very very confusing question because there is a certain confusion about the data relationship, especially once the examples are applied.

Comment: sports count should be `3` due to topic:`3,5,6`

Comment: Yes, it suppose it should be 3, though in my testing I was excluding returning the same result. So if sport wasn't associated with any other thing, and it simply appear by itself in a particular topic, it would be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT keyword, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   topics_keywords 
       INNER JOIN keywords 
               ON topics_keywords.keyword_id = keywords.keyword_id 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT k1.keyword_id AS keyword_id, 
                          topics_keywords.topics_id 
                   FROM   keywords k1 
                          INNER JOIN topics_keywords 
                                  ON topics_keywords.keyword_id = k1.keyword_id 
                   WHERE  keyword = 'baseball') AS temp 
               ON temp.keyword_id != keywords.keyword_id 
                  AND temp.topics_id = topics_keywords.topics_id 
GROUP  BY keyword
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/640f4/15/0)**

EDIT: You can try this also:

```
SELECT keywords.keyword, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   topics_keywords 
       INNER JOIN keywords 
               ON topics_keywords.keyword_id = keywords.keyword_id 
       INNER JOIN keywords k1 
               ON k1.keyword_id != keywords.keyword_id 
       INNER JOIN topics_keywords t1 
               ON t1.keyword_id = k1.keyword_id 
                  AND t1.topics_id = topics_keywords.topics_id 
WHERE  k1.keyword = 'baseball' 
GROUP  BY keyword
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/640f4/19/0)**

I personally feel that first one should be faster, but if you can benchmark it post the results that would be good.

Comment: Oh wow, exactly what I was looking for...and 1/5th the code I had already .. and only 1 query! excellent.

Comment: the second was 100% slower (.0012 sec) as opposed to the first queries (.0006).  However, I don't have much data to go through right now.

Comment: grt thanks for posting the results:) that is what I thought how it should be:)